# binding dynamic dom elements to content.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin that im making use of called content.js http://innovastudio.com/content-builder.aspx

Im adding in dynamic divs to the page which I would like to have the content.js plugin assigned to it, so I can make use of its functionality.

On a single div, or already defined div within the page, I dont appear to have any issues with multiple divs.

However if I add in a div with the same class, I cant seem to bind the plugin to it.

Ive included the code for instantiating the div with the contentbuilder plugin, but I wondering if there is a way to bind it to new elements that are added to the page with the class of "letter". Or if there is a generic way of binding plugins to divs using jquery.

```
$('div.letter').contentbuilder({
            enableZoom:false,
            snippetOpen: true,
            imageselect: 'images.html',
            fileselect: 'images.html',
            snippetFile: '/assets/templates/content-builder/default/snippets.html',
            toolbar: 'left',
            //sourceEditor: false,
            onDrop:function(){
               // function for when an item is dragged into the editable area   
            },
            onRender: function () {
                var coverLength     = $("#coverpage div.row").length;
                var mainContent     = $("#maincontent div.row").length;
                if(coverLength == 0)
                {
                    $("#coverpage").html('<div class="no-content-on-page">Select your content from the right sidebar</div>')
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#coverpage div.no-content-on-page").remove();
                }
                if(mainContent == 0)
                {
                    $("#maincontent").html('<div class="no-content-on-page">Select your content from the right sidebar</div>')
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#maincontent div.no-content-on-page").remove();
                }


                //custom script here
            }      
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must add these divs in a dinamic way, i think that you should init the plugin for each time that you add a new div. To avoid init same div twice, use some class like in the following example:

```
function createLetter(){
   $("body").append('<div class="letter mustBeActivated"></div>');
   initContentBuilder();
}

function initContentBuilder(){


 $('div.letter.mustBeActivated').contentbuilder({
            enableZoom:false,
            snippetOpen: true,
            imageselect: 'images.html',
            fileselect: 'images.html',
            snippetFile: '/assets/templates/content-builder/default/snippets.html',
            toolbar: 'left',
            //sourceEditor: false,
            onDrop:function(){
               // function for when an item is dragged into the editable area   
            },
            onRender: function () {
                var coverLength     = $("#coverpage div.row").length;
                var mainContent     = $("#maincontent div.row").length;
                if(coverLength == 0)
                {
                    $("#coverpage").html('<div class="no-content-on-page">Select your content from the right sidebar</div>')
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#coverpage div.no-content-on-page").remove();
                }
                if(mainContent == 0)
                {
                    $("#maincontent").html('<div class="no-content-on-page">Select your content from the right sidebar</div>')
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#maincontent div.no-content-on-page").remove();
                }


                //custom script here
            }      
        }).removeClass('mustBeActivated');
}
```